# Finding Patent Pending Application

Tags: patent-infringement, application, us61705026

I am developing a product idea similar to another product on the market, and see that this product has a "patent pending" status. In my research, I see that the competing patent lists:

"Patent Pending, U.S. SN 61/705,026"

However, I cannot find any information on this patent reference number after doing extensive research.

Is this patent application not published?

Answer (score 2):

By starting with 61 it is identifiable as the serial number/application number of a **provisional** patent application. They are not published but will be accessible if a non-provisional application is published or issued as a patent and claims the benefit of that provisional application. It is allowed to mark something "patent pending" when a provisional is pending. Including the number is not necessary and takes away a little of the mystery.